# Select data with only specific factors from many

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using T-SQL

I have a table: user session with platform source.

I need to get users who used only "Android" and "Desktop".

Data Example:

```
ID | Source  | DateTime
 1 | Android | 2016-06-01
 1 | Desktop | 2016-06-01
 2 | Android | 2016-06-02
 3 | iOS     | 2016-06-01
 3 | Desktop | 2016-06-02
 3 | Android | 2016-06-03
```

Expected result:

```
ID = 1
```

- ID = 2 is wrong, because it has only "Android"
- ID = 3 is wrong, because it has "IOS"

Comment: What have you attempted thus far? Please show your code. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service - it's expected that you've made an attempt to solve the problem (and show your work), and can point out exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: Already 4 answers submitted @alroc. More to come :D

Comment: @alroc I'm doing a task with few articles. I've done the first one: users only from Android with count group by and join table by itself. But when I met the second article with 2 source, I understood that my way is wrong and I really don't know what logic to use.

Comment: @DaurenSergazin I don't know how to parse that comment

Comment: @alroc accidentally pressed enter. I tried to explain why I don't have any code for this query.

Comment: @DaurenSergazin then please *post that code*. It may be a simple logic error that can be pointed out quickly.

Comment: @alroc as you wish:
`with A as(

    select id, count(distinct source) as count_source

from table

group by id)

select id

from A a

cross apply (select top 1 *

                    from table b

                    where a.id = b.id) c

where a.count_source = 1 and c.source = 'Android'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call this a set-within-sets query.  I like to approach this using `group by` and `having`, because this is a very flexible method for expressing these conditions:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when source = 'Android' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and -- has Android
       sum(case when source = 'Desktop' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and -- has Desktop
       sum(case when source not in ('Android', 'Desktop') then 1 else 0 end) = 0 -- has nothing else
```

Comment: Thank you, I used `HAVING` not so much.
Didn't know about multiple conditions in it for such interesting data filter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN Source='Android' THEN 1 END) + 
                  COUNT(CASE WHEN Source='Desktop' THEN 1 END) AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Source='Desktop' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Source='Android' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select id from your_table
group by id
having 
max(case when source in ('Android') then 1 else 0 end))=1
and
max(case when source in ('Desktop') then 1 else 0 end))=1
and count(distinct source)=2
```

Comment: Edited and include one more method (first one)

Comment: Both queries would still return id 3; the first because the having clause is applied after the where which means that the row with IOS for id 3 is already filtered out which makes the having predicate true. The second would also include id 3 as the count is >= 2 regardless of the inclusion of IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Select * 
from yourtable a 
where a.source = 'Android' 
  and not exist (Select b.id 
                 from yourtable b 
                 where b.id = a.id and b.source <> 'Android')
```

Comment: This would exclude everything that has a source other than Android, which isn't what the OP is asking for.